# how to pass only those values which changed in POST request body

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple state variables, that contains data entered in a form by the user. Since this form is only meant to update the existing values, I have to pass in only those values that have changed from its initial value (the one returned from the GET request).

State:

```
const [name, setName] = useState(props.user?.name ?? null);
const [lang, setLang] = useState(props.user?.lang ?? null);
const [enableChecks, setEnableChecks] = useState(props.user?.checkEnabled ?? false)
```

In the event that the user only changed the name, how can I pass in only name in the request body?

What I have tried: I have the user props, so I have multiple if statements that check if the props matches the state. If it doesn't, then I add it to the request payload. This works, but when there's a lot of state, there will be a lot of if statements, which isn't nice to look at.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Bit of a hacky way with spread. `payload = { ...(prop_changed ? {prop_value} : {}), ...(prop_changed ? {prop_value} : {}) };`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your state in an object, and then only update field state when the `updatedUser` and `user` state values are different.

```js
//use `import` in your real component instead
//import { useState } from 'react';
const { useState } = React;

//fake your user prop
const userProp = {
    name: "Name",
    lang: "English",
  }

function App(props) {
  
  const [user, setUser] = useState(props.user);
  const [updatedUser, setUpdatedUser] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const newlyUpdatedUser = {
      ...updatedUser,
    }
    if(props.user[e.target.name] === e.target.value) {
       delete newlyUpdatedUser[e.target.name]
    } else {
      newlyUpdatedUser[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    }
    setUpdatedUser(newlyUpdatedUser);
    setUser({
       ...user,
       [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  };
  
  console.log(updatedUser)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input value={user.name} name="name" onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Lang:
        <input value={user.lang} name="lang" onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App user={userProp} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having multiple state variables, you can have a single state variable like

`const [state, setState] = useState(props.user)`

and then change handler should look like

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
```

finally, when submitting the form you can make your body data for post request like

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  const requestData = {}  

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(state)){
    if(props.user[key] !== value) {
      requestData[key] = value
    }
  }

  axios.post('some api url', responseData)
}
```